# how to permanently remove a modifier from the UI panel?

Tags: interface, customization

I always click the "Skin" modifier accidentally which freezes up my program, i *never* use this modifier. Is there a way to permanently remove this from the GUI so i don't have to bother carefelly moving my mouse around it?

Comment: i had the same issue. unfortunately its not possible within blender. you would have to remove the button from the blender source code and recompile the code.